# .NET WebApi storing application logging in Azure Application Insights

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights

I have a .Net WebApi project, I would like to store the logging for it (things like errors, information, stacktrackes). I'm not sure what a good place would be I read that I can use log4net and then store it on the same server the application is running on.

However, I read about Application Insight, but am still unsure if it's to store application logging. Can Application Insight serve as an alternative to storing application logging on own server?

Comment: Even if you use AppInsights, it's still always a good idea to have a failsafe local filesystem log because otherwise you'll miss-out on events when AppInsights was unavailable or misconfigured. And of course, AppInsights, like _any_ cloud service, won't be around forever - but how long does your application need to be operational for?

Answer (score 0):

> I can use log4net and then store it on the same server the application is running on.

Not only that but many logging libraries enable you to send the telemetry to other destinations than the local server. log4net for example has [an appender](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender/) that exports the telemetry to application insights.

> However, I read about Application Insight, but am still unsure if it's to store application logging. Can Application Insight serve as an alternative to storing application logging on own server?

It is designed as a cloud based monitoring and logging solution so I wonder what your doubts are given you are still unsure it is capable of storing application logging. Try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger) to get started. If you can share what makes you unsure we might be able to address that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use Application insight of Azure to storing the logs.

Several benefits of it:-

1:- Good Search capability 2: Query based searching 3: Periodically    search 4: Default Azure benefits